# DELL XPS13 9370 Audio problem with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, dell

I have Ubuntu 16.04 (from factory) on my Dell XPS 13 9370 and my audio doesn't always work (I think I am not the only one having this problem). I need to shut down my laptop and turn it on again and sometimes this helps (it is a bit random), but whenever I have the audio working and I suspend my laptop, the audio stops working again (or the volume decreases quiet a lot even though I have the volume settings to the max). The audio seems to work with headphones, at least sometimes. Has anyone been able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Same here have tried literally everything in the forums. The only thing that works and its temporary is to disable the sound in the bios reboot into ubuntu.  Reboot re-enable and reboot into ubuntu.

Works until the machine falls asleep....